# Copy value if date is the same

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

In my book I have 2 spreadsheets, the 1º has 98852 rows with dates and data in front of it, the 2º has 1318 rows with dates and events in front of it, both dates are within the same timeline and the events date match with data date (on 1318 ocasions)

I've ran out of ideas trying to place the events in front of the data in the 1º sheet (if the date matches obviously) otherwise leave blank (except by using search event date to event date to match manually with data)

Example: If Sheet1!Date=Sheet2!Date then copy Event to empty cell (in front of data cell) otherwise blank (x1318 times)

Any sugestions?

Comment: `I've ran out of ideas` Could you share few of those ideas that you tried?

Comment: Sounds like a good candidate for [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)

Comment: Doesn't VLOOKUP require you to know the value which you're looking for?

Comment: I've tried doing =IF(DataDate!A2=$EventDate!A$2;$EventDate!E$2;) in front of Data and paste it down the 98852 rows, but it would just work for 1 event and there's 1318

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that we have Data and Events sheets. Dates are stored at A columns at both sheets. Event is set at B column on Events list. Then you can use formula for the column where you want to show events:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2;Events!$A$2:$B$1319;2;FALSE);"")
```

Please look at this sample sheet: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AvP6NwTpIPzsmIYQqHKhCRL5co867w

Comment: This would had worked in the first place on my spreadsheet but my dates had a few milliseconds of delay between them, asked a teacher for help and he wrote me a VBA Script to do it, thanks anyway!